# Get image URL from XML tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

I'm trying to get an image URL that in XML file, but i can't !

Other Tags like "Description, title, etc" gotten successfully !
XML File:

```html
<DOC>
<DOCNO>annotations/01/1001.eng</DOCNO>
<TITLE>Godchild Gustavo Javier Cuchiparte Umaginga</TITLE>
<DESCRIPTION>a dark-skinned boy wearing a black cap;</DESCRIPTION>
<NOTES></NOTES>
<LOCATION>Quilotoa, Ecuador</LOCATION>
<DATE>April 2002</DATE>
<IMAGE>images/01/1001.jpg</IMAGE>
<THUMBNAIL>thumbnails/01/1001.jpg</THUMBNAIL>
</DOC>
```

My code:

```
Elements titles = doc.getElementsByTag("TITLE");
Elements descriptions = doc.getElementsByTag("DESCRIPTION");
Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("IMAGE");                    
String Imgurl=img.get(0).text(); 
System.out.println(Imgurl);//EMPTY !!
```

Comment: Have you tried `String img = doc.select("IMAGE").first().text()` ?

Comment: Not work !, also an error appear in my JSP page

Comment: Are you sure that you're parsing XML and not HTML? Apparently, your IMAGE tag is being modified when parsing HTML. [Look](http://try.jsoup.org/~vEaxiUap5bIueltvZ2yAZa9IvoA)

Comment: really i don't know how can i know is it HTML or XML , the file that i has is contain these tags !
if it was html ,  how could i deal with it ?

Comment: I just posted an answer, tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you can see [here](http://try.jsoup.org/~vEaxiUap5bIueltvZ2yAZa9IvoA), if `JSoup` parse it as a `HTML` file, your `IMAGE` tag is being modified and becomes `<img>`.

Here is how to parse an `XML` file properly :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(yourXMLstring,"",Parser.xmlParser());
```

---

### EDIT

It does work like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xml = "<DOC><DOCNO>annotations/01/1001.eng</DOCNO><TITLE>Godchild Gustavo Javier Cuchiparte Umaginga</TITLE><DESCRIPTION>a dark-skinned boy wearing a black cap;</DESCRIPTION><NOTES></NOTES><LOCATION>Quilotoa,Ecuador</LOCATION><DATE>April 2002</DATE><IMAGE>images/01/1001.jpg</IMAGE><THUMBNAIL>thumbnails/01/1001.jpg</THUMBNAIL></DOC>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml,"",Parser.xmlParser());
    String image = doc.select("IMAGE").first().text();
    String image2 = doc.getElementsByTag("IMAGE").get(0).text();
    System.out.println(image);
    System.out.println(image2);
}
```

---

### Output

```
images/01/1001.jpg
images/01/1001.jpg
```

---

If it does not work for you, you certainly have another problem. It does not lay in your code.

Comment: not work ! :/ .. this is the file , i upload it to OneDrive acc.
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7B7D65F060AABA4E!108443&authkey=!AMgrSXUS_8X7ZX4&ithint=file%2ceng

Comment: @belal Sorry but it works fine. Try downloading the last version of Jsoup maybe.

Comment: This was old comment (before editing) ,, Now work ! , Thaaanx :D